# ASP.NET- Sending an e-mail

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a Flight booking system and I want to send an E-Mail to the user which wiil contain the E-Ticket of his travel. The E-Ticket is generated dynamically with the booking ID fetched from the database and the other details from the previous pages like Name of the passenger and all. So how can I send him the dynamically generated E-Ticket to his E-Mail ID?

Comment: How is this problem any different from sending an HTML encoded string as an Email message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING:** My original answer to this question suggest using System.Web.Mail for sending e-mails. However, this API has been replaced by System.Net.Mail back in .NET 2.0, and the classes of System.Web.Mail are now all marked obsolete/deprecated.

---

You can use the System.Web.Mail.Mailmessage class:

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
mailMessage.To = "recipient@repipient.com";
mailMessage.From = "sender@sender.com";
mailMessage.Subject = "Email subject";
mailMessage.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html;
mailMessage.Body = "Email body";

System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["mailserver"];
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: All classes in `System.Web.Mail` were superceded in .NET 2.0, and have been deprecated as of .NET 4.0. See Jørn Schou-Rode's answer for more information.

Answer (score 5):

**WARNING**: The accepted answer to this question suggest using `System.Web.Mail` for sending e-mails. However, this API has been replaced by `System.Net.Mail` back in .NET 2.0, and the classes of `System.Web.Mail` are now all marked obsolete/deprecated.

---

Here is the a real simple example of how to construct and send a mail message in .NET:

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
    message.From = new MailAddress("boss@example.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@example.com"));
    message.Subject = "Get back to work!";
    message.Body = "Stop hanging around SO.";

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Actually, the code above can be written much shorter, using the [`SmtpClient.Send()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1s04he7.aspx) method:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send("boss@example.com", "you@example.com",
          "Get back to work!", "Stop hanging around SO.");
```

However, you will often need to use the "verbose" style, in order to be able to set display names on the addresses, change the message content type or add attachments to the message.

Regardless of which you choose, you will need to configure your application with respect to SMTP settings, telling it how to deliver email. In you application configuration file (that would be `web.config` in an ASP.NET application), you will need to add something like this:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="default@example.com">
            <network host="smtp.example.com" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The exact settings depends on how you want your application to deliver mail messages. With the above sample configuration, messages will be relayed through a specified SMTP server. Other solutions includes having the application write messages to a pickup folder, from where the local IIS virtual mail server will process them. See the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240.aspx) for details.

Comment: Also, MailMessage implements IDisposable, so you should either Dispose() the message or put it in a *using* block.

Comment: @Galactic: You are absolutely right, and I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Everyone: Note the in .NET 4.0 the `SmtpClient` class is also `IDisposable`!

Comment: That's a new one.  Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

Emails can be sent using the [System.Net.Mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) namespace. I'd consider using a StringBuilder or String.Format to place the details into the body of the email.

Comment: tats ok.. I have sent an e-mail. How will send the dynamically generated E-Ticket?

Comment: You dynamically create you e-ticket in code via string builder or similar approaches.

Answer (score 1):

System.web.mail is (rightfully) deprecated in asp.net v2.0; you should ignore that answer and listen to the folks who are pointing you to use system.net.mail instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class. That MSDN page contains a complete sample including how to handle attachments.

Or look at [this short tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) in Scott Guthries blog - it also explains the required entries in the configuration file (web.config).

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to send an email in ASP.NET.  Jsut generate the content of the message in your code, pulling in the fixed and dynamic elements to create the full string for the body, then simple send it, either as plain text or HTML.

Here is the basic structure for the call to do a send:

Imports System.Net.Mail

```
        Dim eMessage As New MailMessage(senderAddress, receiverAddress)

        eMessage.Subject = emailSubject
        eMessage.Body = emailBody
        eMessage.IsBodyHtml = emailIsHTML
        eMessage.Attachments.Add(emailAttachment)

        ' send email object
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
        smtp.Send(eMessage)
```

The dynamic part of the content is merely a stringbuilder or similar approach to build up the string from the fixed and dynamic elements you need, adding HTML formatting if you want to use HTML email, etc.