# How to send emails from my web application?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [ASP.NET- Sending an e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767694/asp-net-sending-an-e-mail)
>   [how to send mail using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354436/how-to-send-mail-using-c)

How can I send emails from my ASP.NET web application?

Comment: ... How about give us some more information

Comment: This isn't really a question. You should provide more information and formulate a proper question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354436/how-to-send-mail-using-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467930/how-to-send-mail-in-asp-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767694/asp-net-sending-an-e-mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("sender@email.com", "Sender Name"), new MailAddress("email@email.com"));
mailMessage.Subject = "Some subject";
mailMessage.Body = msg;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Setup configuration in web.config

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network
         host="mail.email.com"
         port="587"
         userName="user@email.com"
         password="xxxx" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) and the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) classes.